# webscraping javascript from an array to the search box

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Hello I'm trying to do webscraping by trying to insert every word I have in the array to the search box and return the frequency number of the following website: http://www.wordandphrase.info/frequencyList.asp  but I'm getting only the html elemnts and not the text with every position for every word in the array. Thanks!

```js
function you(){
var array= ["amid", "chants", "briefed", "boast", "boasts", "dare", "clad", "cod", "brickwork", "adamant", "corrugated", "axiomatic", "attrition", "conundrum", "cloaked", "concoction", "adjust", "allotments", "bump", "brimstone", "applauding", "bestowed", "contriving", "chiefly", "countrymen", "bowels", "carted", "daft", "crammed", "commonest", "condone", "aplenty", "allies", "awestruck", "dazzling", "awed", "blurb", "blooming"]

emptyArray= [];

for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
var word= document.querySelector("input#w1").value;
array[i]= document.createTextNode(word)
emptyArray.push(word);
}
}
```

// emptyArray
// =>  input type="text" id="w1" name="w1" value size="15" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">, ,

Ok, so I would add the following to make it clearer: If I want to search for the word "amid" in the "input#w1" search box I'll get a table on the right where the value I'm interested in will be "14912" which is located inside the: document.querySelector("div.pagecontainer > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)").textContent;

and I don't know how to do this same process for every single word in the array and get the number which is located inside the table elements I wrote above.

Comment: An implied question is not the same thing as an explicit one. Furthermore, there's absolutely no attempt in your code to **(0)** compare anything to anything else and **(1)** even make use of the data in `array` - all you do is overwrite each element in it with a text-node that contains the value of the `input#w1`

Comment: Exactly, I don't know how to do that, I think I've understood me.

Comment: Well, you work out what you want, then request information from others on how to achieve this. That request would constitute a question. Irrelevant if you've understood yourself - you need to aim to have your readers understand you. Read more about the site's expectations from users here: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: jajaja there was a mistake instead of " I've understood me" it was " you've understood me". Moreover, I don't think it's difficult although I don't know how to do it myself yet. That's why I ask.

Comment: I edited  my question, it's nearly at the bottom, starting with " Ok, so I would add the following..." hope this helps.